# Changing AWS configuration directory

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS stores the default configuration files in `~/.aws/`.

I'm trying to have all hidden directories inside `~/.config/`, and would like to change the default location to `~/.config/aws/`

How would I do this from the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a non-default location for the config file by setting the AWS_CONFIG_FILE environment variable to another local path.

```
Steps I used:
1. Create a folder with the name of your choice. I used .awscheck (mkdir .awscheck)
2. Create a file named credentials within the folder.
3. Configure the variable. (export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=~/.awscheck/credentials)
4. Run aws configure and add your values.
```

Similarly, if you want to store configurations, you can create a config file and add the configurations like profiles and regions in the config file.

Comment: This is same for credentials as well.

Answer (score 5):

Custom locations for `config` and `credentials` files can be specified using two [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html):

- **AWS_CONFIG_FILE**: Specifies the location of the file that the AWS CLI uses to store configuration profiles. The default path is `~/.aws/config`.
- **AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE**: Specifies the location of the file that the AWS CLI uses to store access keys. The default path is `~/.aws/credentials`.

Comment: I've added custom locations for both parameters in my `zshrc`

Comment: @Saurabh Glad to hear that it worked out. Thanks for letting me know.